# Making speed time chart / extracting the data in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I have used the follwing code to read an excel file:

```js
// Requiring the module
const reader = require('xlsx')
  
// Reading our test file
const file = reader.readFile('./report.xlsx')
  
let data = []
  
const sheets = file.SheetNames
  
for(let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++)
{
   const temp = reader.utils.sheet_to_json(
        file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[i]])
   temp.forEach((res) => {
      data.push(res)
   })
}
  
// Printing data
console.log(data);
```

The data is displayed in the console like this:
[output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ1mJ.png)

but when I am reading the properties of the objects, it is shown like this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94bbG.png)

only two properties are displayed and one of them is empty.

**My questions:**

1. How can I replace the property names like "__Empty_1".
   **2. How to really read a column of excel in an array?** 
   **(my motive is to create a speed time chart by importing data from columns of xlsx file)**

Answer (score 0):

You might find `node-xlsx` module useful. This is a module that relies on the `xlsx` module (that you are using).
This module worked for me.

The example spreadsheet am using is:
[assets/spreadsheet.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcpVY.png)

The code that I ended up with:

```
const xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
var obj = xlsx.parse(__dirname + '/assets/spreadsheet.xlsx'); //Parses the file
console.log(obj)

// Output:
// [ { name: 'Sheet1', data: [ [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ] } ]
```

The obj is an array containing all the sheets of the spreadsheet, currently am having one sheet only.

```
console.log(obj[0].name) // Output: Sheet1
console.log(obj[0].data) // Output: [ [ 'Sample Data' ], [ 1 ], [ 2 ], [ 3 ] ]
```

The element of the array(first sheet), has a name and data properties. Which you can see here.

The data is an array, the first dimension being the row, and the second being the column.
obj[0].data[1][0] refers to row 2 and column 1.